# How can you find which carrier a LG D803 is locked to?

Tags: sim-unlocking, lg-g2, carriers

I bought a LG D803 and it came locked to an unknown carrier. All the unlock services require the information of which carrier the phone is locked to give me an unlock code. So, how can I find that out?

Answer (score 0):

The System Version of the device is usually unique to a carrier, due to the changes carriers make to the stock software in most countries. You can find that value in `Settings > About Device > System Version` and plug it into Google.